# Why am not able to see the GithubAction work flow logs

Tags: github, continuous-integration, action

While cicd github action in yml file ,am not able to see the logs.Am using private repo.i have access to read and write the repo.Main job of migration is failed.I want to see the reason for that

how can i see the logs even if success and fail

[image: workflow picture]